# HTML CSS - How to render SQL nicely

Tags: html, css

I am looking to render SQL code on my webpage. I am making tutorials and i would like to display SQL snippets to my visitors. Are there some librairies out there or best practices to do that?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you've tried already? What do you want it to look like? Maybe dump the SQL into <code> tags, and style that how you want? Use white-space: pre-wrap to keep the output with proper line breaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is StackOverflow I will recommend the one that [StackExchange is using](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109) - Google's [Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) library, which [supports SQL](https://github.com/google/code-prettify#for-which-languages-does-it-work).

You would have to include the library to your site:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
```

And then write your example

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
SELECT name FROM users;
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually when you want to neatly display code on a webpage, CSS isn't enough. If you want more sophisticated code coloring and formatting, you'll most likely need to write javascript in order to detect keywords, values strings etc. Luckily with the dev community being what it is, there are already options to do this for many different languages. I'd recommend [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) as it offers support for many languages, it's easy to use and customize.